# Follow a post in SharePoint 2007 blog

Tags: 2007, blog

Is there any OOTB way to follow a post in SharePoint 2007 blog? I mean maybe get an email each time the post is commented or changed?

Thanks
Eliya Amanoeel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alert Feature should works. You can get an email every time the post is update

Comment: Perfekt Mr. Slavatore!